# Python: plot changing float values as colours

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of of tuples of three colors:

```
v = ([0.16091847477176702, 0.4337815920028113, 0.40529993322542174)
(0.15019057645364922, 0.40486281920262385, 0.44494660434372696)
(0.14017787135673926, 0.44453863125578225, 0.4152834973874785)
(0.13083267993295664, 0.41490272250539673, 0.45426459756164661)
(0.17697859494133705, 0.36303988219222216, 0.45998152286644078)
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824)
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824)
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824)
(0.15406618756053894, 0.37407489744412198, 0.47185891499533911)
(0.20019069588580043, 0.32419824445157241, 0.47561105966262723)
(0.20019069588580043, 0.32419824445157241, 0.47561105966262723)
(0.17349860310102702, 0.34763847852469609, 0.47886291837427691)
(0.16193202956095856, 0.39112924662304965, 0.44693872381599176)]
```

Each value in the tuple I untuitively interpret as a color (for example: how yellow, how red, how blue), so together each  tuple gives me a colour (as the mix of the first one, second and third one). Is it possible to plot the change of the colors using matplotlib? My initial idea was to use RGB, but RGB takes integers, and the precision of those number is quite important. Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: the RGB components are integers so you will always lose precision, the error that you will make will be 1/256

Comment: You need to do some image processing. Subtract the mean from the data, normalise values between -1 and 1, and do scatter plot in 3D,  I think that would give some intuition. Could you describe more about your problem? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ShreyasPimpalgaonkar I want to see the color change over time, where v[0] is time t0, v[1] is time t1 etc

Comment: I think what I suggested should work fine. Well, I see the values in the first column are right from 0.2 to 0.13 -how many decimals of precision do you want here?

Comment: Note that the human eye will not be able to distiguish colors which differ by less than 1/256, so if this is about visualization, the RGB restriction you mention is meaningless. Also note that Matplotlib is capable of accepting float values, so there is no need to convert to integers first. In total, it is not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

floats between 0 and 1 are good values for rgb in matplotlib. here's a small example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = [(0.16091847477176702, 0.4337815920028113, 0.40529993322542174),
(0.15019057645364922, 0.40486281920262385, 0.44494660434372696),
(0.14017787135673926, 0.44453863125578225, 0.4152834973874785),
(0.13083267993295664, 0.41490272250539673, 0.45426459756164661),
(0.17697859494133705, 0.36303988219222216, 0.45998152286644078),
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824),
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824),
(0.16591743275750348, 0.40284988955520828, 0.43123267768728824),
(0.15406618756053894, 0.37407489744412198, 0.47185891499533911),
(0.20019069588580043, 0.32419824445157241, 0.47561105966262723),
(0.20019069588580043, 0.32419824445157241, 0.47561105966262723),
(0.17349860310102702, 0.34763847852469609, 0.47886291837427691),
(0.16193202956095856, 0.39112924662304965, 0.44693872381599176)]

y = np.arange(len(v))
for i in range(len(v)):
    plt.plot(y[i], 0, marker='o', ls='', c=v[i], markersize=20)

plt.show()
```

and the result:

[image]

it's subtle but it works